# How to fix cPanel after restore a droplet from snapshot?

Tags: cpanel

During the cPanel setup the hostname of the original droplet was set as: `srv.domain.com`

On DigitalOcean I made a snapshot and created a new droplet from snapshot.
I changed IP address in **Basic WebHost Manager® Setup** -> **Basic Config** on the new droplet.

After switching DNS to the new droplet when I open mydomain.com

I get errors:

`SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`. The certificate is only valid for the following names: `srv.domain.com`, `www.srv.domain.com`

SSL report for `srv.domain.com` shows the Issuer - cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority

So what's happening is the web server for one domain uses different certs for other service domain. It is replacing the certificate to those used for service domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change IP:

   - Basic WebHost Manager® Setup.
   - Home » Account Functions » Change Site’s IP Address.
2. Update license to match the new IP cPanel/WHM store.